# Getting "Either HibernateOperations or SessionFactory must be provided" when configuring custom HibernateItemWriter

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-batch

SO I'm trying to build an app that writes to a MySQL db using Hibernate, and having a heck of a time trying to get it to work. In a nutshell, it's not seeing the Session, even though I have one configured and Autowired. Here's what I have code wise.

First the configuration of said app:

```
@EnableBatchProcessing
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages="com.lcbo")
@EnableIntegration
public class BatchConfig {

@Autowired
private JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

@Autowired
private StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

@Bean
public Job processLCBOInventory(@Qualifier("getCurrentLCBODataStep") final Step getCurrentLCBODataStep,
                                @Qualifier("getLCBOStoreDataStep") final Step getLCBOStoreDataStep,
                                final JobExecutionListenerConfig jelcListener
                                ) {
    return jobBuilderFactory
            .get("processLCBOInventory")
            .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
            .start(getCurrentLCBODataStep)
            .next(getLCBOStoreDataStep)
            .listener(jelcListener)
            .build();

}

@Bean
public Step getLCBOStoreDataStep(final LCBOStoreReader lcboStoreReader,
                                 final LCBOStoreProcessor lcboStoreProcessor,
                                 final LCBOStoreWriter lcboStoreWriter,
                                 final ExecutionContextPromotionListener listener) throws Exception {

    return stepBuilderFactory
            .get("getLCBOStoreDataStep")
            .<LCBOStore, LCBOStore>chunk(inventoryTrackerProperties.getDefaults().getChunkSize())
            .reader(lcboStoreReader.read())
            .processor(lcboStoreProcessor)
            .writer(lcboStoreWriter)
            .listener(listener)
            .build();
}
```

Then, the writer:

```
@Component
public class LCBOStoreWriter extends HibernateItemWriter<LCBOStore> {

        @Autowired
private LCBOStoreService lcboStoreService;

@Autowired
private DatabaseConfig dbConfigy;

private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LCBOStoreWriter.class);

@Override
public void write(List<? extends LCBOStore> lcboStoreItems) {

    for (LCBOStore lcboStoreItem : lcboStoreItems) {
        lcboStoreService.addNewStore(lcboStoreItem);
    }

}
```

and the DatabaseConfig file contents:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.lcbo.domain")
public class DatabaseConfig {

    @Autowired
    private LCBOInventoryTrackerProperties properties;

    @Bean
    public EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory() throws SQLException {

        final LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        factoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());
        factoryBean.setJpaDialect(new HibernateJpaDialect());
        factoryBean.setJpaProperties(getHibernateProperties());
        factoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter());
        factoryBean.setPackagesToScan("com.lcbo.domain");
        factoryBean.setPersistenceProviderClass(HibernatePersistenceProvider.class);
        factoryBean.setPersistenceUnitName("persistenceUnit");
        factoryBean.afterPropertiesSet();


        return factoryBean.getObject();
    }

    @Bean(destroyMethod = "")
    public DataSource dataSource() throws SQLException {
        BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();

        dataSource.setDriverClassName(properties.getDb().getDriver());
        dataSource.setUrl(properties.getDb().getUrl());
        dataSource.setUsername(properties.getDb().getUsername());
        dataSource.setPassword(properties.getDb().getPassword());

        return dataSource;
    }
```

even tried SessionFactory itself, like this

```
public LocalSessionFactoryBean getSessionFactory() throws SQLException {
    LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
    sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());
    sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "com.bytestree.model" });
    sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(getHibernateProperties());

    return sessionFactory;
}
```

but with no dice. I also tried injecting a SessionFactory instance into the setSessionFactory that HibernateItemWriter comes with, with again, no dice.

I know I've got something wrong, the question is where is it expecting SessionFactory to be placed to be reconized by the application, or if I've configured this writer anywhere close to being correct at all?

EDIT: As requested, the stacktrace that shows in intellj upon running this code.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'LCBOInventoryWriter' defined in file [C:\workspace\LCBOInventoryTracker\target\classes\com\lcbo\writer\LCBOInventoryWriter.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Either HibernateOperations or SessionFactory must be provided
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1628) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:866) ~[spring-context-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542) ~[spring-context-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:737) [spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:1.5.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:370) [spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:1.5.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:314) [spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:1.5.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1162) [spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:1.5.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1151) [spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:1.5.1.RELEASE]
    at com.lcbo.config.LCBOBatchConfig.main(LCBOBatchConfig.java:157) [classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147) [idea_rt.jar:na]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Either HibernateOperations or SessionFactory must be provided
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.state(Assert.java:392) ~[spring-core-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.item.database.HibernateItemWriter.afterPropertiesSet(HibernateItemWriter.java:93) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1687) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1624) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    ... 20 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Where are you setting the `SessionFactory` on the writer?

Comment: Can you show the complete stack trace/error? How do you set up spring batch? I notice that in your `LCBOStoreWriter.write()` you are casting Session to SessionFactory. That won't work! Try setting the SessionFactory of the HibernateItemWriter using `SessionFactory sessionFactory = entityManagerFactory.unwrap(SessionFactory.class);`

Comment: The `HibernateItemWriter` needs an explicitly wired `sessionFactory` that is checked in the `afterPropertiesSet` method. Also imho your application is flawed as you shouldn't need a `SessionFactory` and `EntityMangerFactory`. Why are you even using the `HibernateItemWriter`? You should be using the `JpaItemWriter` instead, for which you don't need the hack/workaround you have in place now.

Comment: @MichaelMinella I had it where SessionFactory was set using this.setSessionFactory(databaseConfig.getSessionFactory()) in the writer to no effect.

Comment: @M.Deinum Tried adding it to afterPropertiesSet() in the writer, but same result. Have updated the code to reflect the changes. Tried switching to JpaItemWriter, with the same result (will keep trying that one as I dind't know of it's existance until just now.). As for why I was using it, was doing Hibernate and figured that was the way to go? Like I said I'm coming in completely unknowing of how to set this up properly. And online resource are poor at best I've found.

Comment: @qtips Will include the complete stack trace in the original msg. I also gave the suggested code change with the same error message appearing. I've also included the configuration for the application

Comment: Don't you have a configuration where you setup the `Job` and `Step`?

Comment: @qtips apologies, I've included the Job and Step config in the initial post

Comment: Since HibernateItemWriter is a third-party dependency, I think may be better to setup LCBOStoreWriter as a `@Bean` instead of `@Component`. Similarly, you can create the sessionFactory as a @Bean pretty much as you did with getSessionFactory(). This can then be used in your LCBOStoreWriter `@Bean`. I can elaborate as an answer if want to.

Comment: @qtips If you could I'd welcome an elaboration on that.

Comment: Just use a plain `JpaItemWriter` you don't need to extend it, that is your whole issue here, your extension is destroying the proper working of the writer.

Comment: @M.Deinum IN a way, your advice worked. I've posted my solution in an answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So from how it sounds with the feedback that I received, it is as I feared, I had created a frakenstein solution cobbled from multiple sources online. With a lot of help and some trial and error, I solved it by doing the following.

First, here's how the writer looks now.

```
@Component
public class LCBOStoreWriter implements ItemWriter<LCBOStore> {

    @Autowired
    private DatabaseConfig dbConfig;

    @Override
    public void write(List<? extends LCBOStore> items) throws Exception {

        JpaItemWriter wr = new JpaItemWriter();

        wr.setEntityManagerFactory(dbConfig.entityManagerFactory());
        wr.write(items);

    }
}
```

EDIT: I extended the writer mainly because of seperation of functionality into its own class. I've found that these things like to expand as the project goes on so figure seperate them at the start. Plus I like the look. That being said, it's not required and as @M. Deinum pointed out can make things more complex then needed. Unless you know you'll need to extend functionality with a custom writer, or have a silly thing like me where you find separation looks better code wise, go with what @qtips created, then add the method in your Step configuration for your writer.

Then LCBOStore, which is a combo of a java object and Hibernate/JPA annotations.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "store")
public class LCBOStore {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "addressLineOne", length = 255)
    private String addressLineOne;

    @Column(name = "addressLineTwo", length = 255)
    private String addressLineTwo;

    @Column(name = "city", length = 255)
    private String city;

    @Column(name = "postalCode", length = 10)
    private String postalCode;

    @Column(name = "latitude", length = 255)
    private String latitude;

    @Column(name = "longitude", length = 255)
    private String longitude;

    @Column(name = "updatedAt", length = 255)
    private String updatedAt; //Convert to Date

//getters and setters

}
```

The entityManagerFactory class that's autowired in:

```
@Bean
public EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory() throws SQLException {

    final LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    factoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());
    factoryBean.setJpaDialect(new HibernateJpaDialect());
    factoryBean.setJpaProperties(getHibernateProperties());
    factoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter());
    factoryBean.setPackagesToScan("com.lcbo.batch.domain");
   factoryBean.setPersistenceProviderClass(HibernatePersistenceProvider.class);
    factoryBean.setPersistenceUnitName("persistenceUnit");
    factoryBean.afterPropertiesSet();


    return factoryBean.getObject();
}
```

and the configuration for the step

```
@Bean
public Step getLCBOStoreDataStep(final LCBOStoreReader lcboStoreReader,
                                 final LCBOStoreProcessor lcboStoreProcessor,
                                 final LCBOStoreWriter lcboStoreWriter,
                                 final ExecutionContextPromotionListener listener) throws Exception {

    return stepBuilderFactory
            .get("getLCBOStoreDataStep")
            .<LCBOStore, LCBOStore>chunk(inventoryTrackerProperties.getDefaults().getChunkSize())
            .reader(lcboStoreReader.read())
            .processor(lcboStoreProcessor)
            .writer(lcboStoreWriter)
            .listener(listener)
            .build();
}
```

I'd like to thank qtips, and M. Deinum for their help on this. Was most appreciated!

Comment: Which is still a Frankenstein solution you don't need that wrapper... It doesn't add anything but complexity. which also makes me fear for your other reader and processors.

Comment: I think it is great that you managed to get it to run! It can be a challenge to get the bean stuff running the first time. As @M.Deinum suggests, try getting it to work without extending the hibernate writer and you'll start owning spring batch ;)

Comment: @M.Deinum I beleive I understand where you're coming from and have put in an addendum for the answer that unless you know you'll need to extend your writer/processor (pr are silly and just like that style), just put it in the config style where you've configured your step.

Comment: If you extend/wrap things at leat know what you are doing. SOme writers implenent more interfaces and your way of wrapping (only with `ItemWriter`) might break properly functioning of those writers (or other components). Hence my strong suggestion of not extending the defaults as generally thins break without properly understanding Spring Batch in detail.

Answer (score 1):

Since HibernateItemWriter is a third-party dependency, I think it may be better to setup LCBOStoreWriter as a `@Bean` instead of `@Component`, and set the `sessionFactory` there.

Remove the `@Component` from LCBOStoreWriter and add the following to `BatchConfig`

```
@Bean
public LCBOStoreWriter lCBOStoreWriter() {
    LCBOStoreWriter wr = new LCBOStoreWriter();
    wr.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory())
    return wr;
}
```

You may need to setup lcboStoreService and dbConfigy if they are not autowired. Alternatively, you can inject them some other way, I don't remember all the ways...

```
@Bean
public SessionFactory sessionFactory() throws SQLException {
    LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
    sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());
    sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "com.bytestree.model" });
    sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(getHibernateProperties());
    return sessionFactory.getObject();
}
```

Comment: So autowired dbConfig, modified sessionFactory to fit your example, modified the Step configuration and added lCBOStoreWriter to Batch Config, but sadly still the exact same error. However, tried the following: wr.setSessionFactory(dbConfig.entityManagerFactory().unwrap(‌​SessionFactory.class‌​)); and the error is replaced with "contains is not valid without active transaction" error

Comment: Can you debug the lCBOStoreWriter() and getLCBOStoreDataStep() and verify that the sessionfactory is set of not? Actually, I agree with @m-deinum.  Why are you extending HibernateItemWriter? You should probably just set it up as bean with a session factory. The Processor should simply return the hibernate entities and writer should write them automatically, without the need of service.

Comment: Have you seen this guide? https://spring.io/guides/gs/batch-processing/ it is a good stating point which you can extend it to work with hibernate. Here you will set up data source with application.properties instead of setting it up in config. And spring boot will provide you with datasource. Then I think you can autowire sessionfactory / entityManager

Comment: Do tell how it goes :)

Comment: I found a solution of sorts. I've posted my answer below.